# Problem with singleton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

### i Have singleton

```
 @interface CartesManager : NSObject {


NSMutableArray *carteMan ; 
NSInteger indexCarteCourante ;
NSInteger numImage ; 
BOOL isEditable ;

}
```

I want to change the contents of the last cell of the Array "Carteman. I took the last box of the Array.

```
-(void)DoneButton :(id)sender {

int Valeur ; 

Valeur = ([[CartesManager sharedInstance].carteMan count] -1 );

Carte *uneCarte= [[[CartesManager sharedInstance].carteMan]objectAtIndex:Valeur]; //Expected ":" before ";" token 


 switch (indexsectioncurrent) {
     case 0:
         uneCarte.titre = textField.text ;
         break;
     case 1:
         uneCarte.nom = textField.text ; 
         break;
    case 2:
         uneCarte.prenom = textField.text ; 
        break;
    case 3:
         uneCarte.adresse = textField.text ; 
        break;
    case 4:
         uneCarte.phone = textField.text ; 
        break;
   case 5:
        uneCarte.mobile = textField.text ; 
       break;
   case 6:
        uneCarte.mail = textField.text ; 
       break;
    case 7:
         uneCarte.site = textField.text ; 
        break;
    case 8:
         uneCarte.commentaire = textField.text ; 
        break;

     default:
         break;

 }  
uneCarte.image1 = image1CarteV ; 
uneCarte.image2 = image2CarteV;





[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

### }

### This is my Problem

```
         Carte *uneCarte= [[[CartesManager sharedInstance].carteMan]objectAtIndex:Valeur]; //Expected ":" before ";" token**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't need [] when accessing a property:

```
Carte *uneCarte= [[CartesManager sharedInstance].carteMan objectAtIndex:Valeur];
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, put a space between the `.carteMan]` and `objectAtIndex:`. Also, it's not clear that you've declared `carteMan` to be a property. You may need to add:

```
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *carteMan;
```

to your header file, and:

```
@synthesize carteMan;
```

to your implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

When you go through the line causing the error in the order of execution, this is what happens:

1. `[CartesManager sharedInstance];` This returns a  CartesManager object
2. `result.carteMan;` This takes the result of the first step and gets the property named `carteMan`, returning an NSMutableArray object
3. `[result];` This is an incomplete message. It has a receiver, but no command. I don't think you want to perform this step at all, as it appears the you want to call `objectAtIndex:` on the array from step 2.

To fix your problem, change your code from

```
Carte *uneCarte= [[[CartesManager sharedInstance].carteMan]objectAtIndex:Valeur];
```

to

```
Carte *uneCarte= [[CartesManager sharedInstance].carteMan objectAtIndex:Valeur];
```